# What is better to use, FeRAM or MRAM? Why?

Tags: memory, mram

FeRAM and MRAM have almost the same characteristics from electronic point of view although the physics behind is different - feroelectric material and magnetoresistive material. Their properties: non-volatile, write/read cycles number, write/read speeds etc are almost the same. Then why a company is choosing to use FeRAM instead of MRAM, or MRAM instead of FeRAM?

Do you think that this are the future memories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the only disadvantage of MRAM is more power for writes.  Unless things have changed, write speed is faster on MRAM and there is infinite endurance, unlike the limited number of cycles for FeRAM.  The issue is if MRAM can get into the main stream and get anywhere close to Flash as far as cell size.  Without the same yield, prices can't be competitive.  That drives most things.